# Android TabHost show tabs in all the activities

Tags: android, tabs

In my **Android** app I'm using **TabHost** to work on some tab functionality. tab works fine. but in my app each tab contains several icons related to activities and when each activity starts it take over the whole screen. instead I want to show tabs when all the activities are running.

for instance take following screen as my tab view.
[image]

and when I click on the icon the second screen is as follow.
[image]

in there I can't see the tabs and in my case I wanna be able to see the tabs in the second activity too.
 how can I implement this. can I use Fragments in this. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Yes, Use the fragment checkout this blog http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: ya thanks. but I'm looking for when I starts a activity in a tab it takes all the screen. need a solution for that.

Comment: can you post the reference image that you need to implement in your Question

Comment: thanks. I post images. is it clear now

Comment: is the thing I'm trying to do is impossible ?????? can't I load an activity to a certain part of the screen ????

Comment: yea it is impossible to create that either you can use above part of activity transparent but that is a best practice instead of that use fragment as best option and replace it appropriately